# Rails + MySQL on Mavericks - Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-mavericks

When I run a Rails (`rails s`) app on my localhost (OSX Mavericks), I get this error

```
message:/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': dlopen(/Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/rubydev/logistadvise/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure how I already installed MySQL, but I guess it's in the subfolder called `Cellar`.

Here's how my `bash_profile` looks like:

```
MYSQL=/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PG_DUMP="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/"
#PATH=$PG_DUMP:$PATH
...
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. Because I installed it with brew, the location of the `DYLD` changed. Try this:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql-5.1.67-osx10.6-x86_64/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Check if the path above exists first with something like the following and obviously adjust the export path accordingly:

`ls -1 /usr/local/mysql-5.1.67-osx10.6-x86_64`

You could probably make a symbolic link or something. It was kind of annoying for me, but using the correct path fixed it for me.

And also try `which mysql` to check if you have mysql in your path. If you don't get any output obviously the paths are messed up.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.16/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

This should work for you.