# Install mysql2 -v '0.3.19' via bundle (Gemfile) on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I have an error while trying to 'bundle install' when listing 'mysql2' on the Gemfile on OSX Lion. I'm currenly building an app with Rails. If I run 'bundle install', it hangs forever. First I tried to fix the issue by modifying the gem file to 'gem 'mysql2', :git => 'git://github.com/sodabrew/mysql2.git', :ref => 'a2800f'', as suggested here: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/pull/654. The infinite loop got fixed, I ran 'bundle install' sucessfully but when I run 'rake db:create', I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mysql2-a2800f86754b/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mysql2-a2800f86754b/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mysql2-a2800f86754b/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/macbook/Desktop/tutorial/billingleap2/moviestore/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macbook/Desktop/tutorial/billingleap2/moviestore/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

I also try to 'brew install mysql' and it worked, but then on 'rake db:create', I got this error:

```
#<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"moviestore_development"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
#<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)>
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8","pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"moviestore_test"}, {:charset=>"utf8", :collation=>"utf8_unicode_ci"}
(If you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)
```

So then I 'brew uninstall mysql' and that problem was gone, but now I have the first one.

Trying 'gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.19'' also hangs.

What could be the problem?

Comment: please paste your Gemfile and gemfile.lock here

Comment: Is mysql server process running and accepting connections? The error message suggests that no process is accepting connections.

Two guesses:
1) there is no mysql daemon process running
2) there is a mysql daemon process running but it does not accept any local connections.

I think 1) is more likely. How did you start mysql after installing it?

Comment: Here is the Gemfile: http://pastie.org/10365361 and here is the gemfile.lock: http://pastie.org/10365363

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using bundler, you have to fix the first issue (why bundle install is failing) and install the `mysql2` gem using bundler. There must have some gem dependency issue that you need to look at.

And, you should run: `bundle exec rake db:migrate` as you are using bundler and Gemfile etc. that will ensure your rake task runs in the context of the current project.

#### Update: 1

If you already ran: `bundle install` successfully and installed the `mysql2` gem successfully, then try running:

```
`bundle exec rake db:create`
```

If this causes you the specified error (which means your `libmysqlclient` library is not loading for some reason):

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mysql2-a2800f86754b/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mysql2-a2800f86754b/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/macbook/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mysql2-a2800f86754b/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/macbook/Desktop/tutorial/billingleap2/moviestore/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/macbook/Desktop/tutorial/billingleap2/moviestore/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

then you should look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546698/library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-16-dylib-error-when-trying-to-run-rails-serv) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24328935/rails-mysql-on-mavericks-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib) which have some prescribed solutions for similar issue. Try those see if that works.

#### Update: 2

So, `mysql` gem has some development dependencies which needs to be installed in your system before you can actually use mysql. Do the following:

```
sudo gem install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo gem install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
sudo gem install mysql
```

And, then try again:

```
bundle install
```

#### Update: 3

First, to find your socket file:

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket
```

It will give you something like this:

```
| socket                                            | /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Then, add a line to your config/database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: xxxx
  database: xxxx
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Hi, Rakibul! Thanks so much! ;) This is what is failing while `bundle install`: `checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no`. I don't anymore have mysql install on my machine. Maybe the problem is that I installed it and uinstalled it with brew?

Comment: do you have the project on github?

Comment: @Sofía please try my Update: 2 and see if that fixes your issue. Let me know!

Comment: Thanks Rakibul! I have been able to install mysql and also to `bundle install`. But now when `bundle exec rake db:create`, I got http://pastie.org/10365507

Comment: awesome. we are very close now. You just need to start your local mysql server

Comment: Ok, I know what happened. I needed to start the server in order to make the migration. I run `mysql.server start`, and it got fixed! :) Thanks so much!

Comment: I also installed mysql with brew: `brew install mysql` and then (in Gemfile) `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'` and then `bundle install`. Sucess!

Comment: Yes, exactly, you needed to start your mysql server. Awesome, all is good, right?

Comment: Yeah! I feel so dummy right now.. but I guess you learn through mistakes. Thanks so much! Everything is great!